# How can I solve this error in PLSQL / DELETE TRIGGER error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to write a code in plsql that does something like this:
before you delete a row, this trigger will check out if the row has children, if that's the case, children becomes children of their grandfather and then the row proceeds to be deleted.

So, this is what i have for now :

```
CREATE TABLE sucursal
(
    codsuc     NUMBER (8) PRIMARY KEY,
    ganancia   NUMBER (8) NOT NULL CHECK (ganancia > 0),
    sucpadre   NUMBER (8) REFERENCES sucursal
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER borrar_sucursal
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON sucursal
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (old.sucpadre IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Bueno pues lo intente');
    hijo_de_abuelo (:old.codsuc);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hijo_de_abuelo (codigo IN sucursal.codsuc%TYPE)
IS
    gato   sucursal.sucpadre%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT sucpadre
      INTO gato
      FROM sucursal
     WHERE codsuc = codigo;

    FOR gallo IN (SELECT *
                    FROM sucursal
                   WHERE sucpadre = codigo)
    LOOP
        UPDATE sucursal
           SET sucpadre = gato
         WHERE codsuc = gallo.codsuc;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

So, this is what happens when i try to delete a row in SQL console:

```
SQL> delete from sucursal where codsuc = 2;
Bueno pues lo intente
delete from sucursal where codsuc = 2
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table PANCRACI0.SUCURSAL is mutating, trigger/function may not see
it
ORA-06512: at "PANCRACI0.HIJO_DE_ABUELO", line 7
ORA-06512: at "PANCRACI0.BORRAR_SUCURSAL", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PANCRACI0.BORRAR_SUCURSAL'
```

Any help would be great guys.

Comment: You are selecting and then updating the same table this is "mutating" e.g. see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write a procedure to call if a row in the table should be deleted instead of directly issuing a `DELETE` statement. In that procedure the children first get relocated before the node is finally deleted. That however may require you to change the applications using the table.

Alternatively rename the table to put it into the "background".

```
ALTER TABLE sucursal
            RENAME TO sucursal_t;
```

Then create a view with the same name the table had before you renamed it. That leaves the view in the "foreground".

```
CREATE VIEW sucursal
AS
SELECT codsuc,
       ganancia,
       sucpadre
       FROM sucursal_t;
```

On that view you can now place an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to intercept `DELETE`s. The trigger first relocates the children of a node, that is about to be deleted and then deletes the node in the "background" table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER borrar_sucursal
                          INSTEAD OF DELETE
                          ON sucursal
                          FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bueno pues lo intente');

    UPDATE sucursal_t
           SET sucpadre = :old.sucpadre
           WHERE sucpadre = :old.codsuc;

    DELETE FROM sucursal_t
           WHERE codsuc = :old.codsuc;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2f73d6171eef00603531b1229070c3f1)

That way your existing code can still use the table as before.